# How do I correctly display a file extension from an HTML POST file using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, file, pathinfo

I am attempting to echo the extension of an uploaded tax document. The document can be any image or a pdf. I plan on using the extension to rename the file with its proper extension later in the code.

Currently it does not echo the extension.

I have attempted a few different methods and looked at documentation and forums. I seem to still be doing something wrong.

My HTML:

`<input type="file" class="" id="TaxFile" name="TaxFile" accept="image/*,application/pdf" ><br /><br />`

My PHP:

`$taxpath = pathinfo($_FILES["TaxFile"]["tmp_name"]);
echo $taxpath['extension'] . "\n123";`

echos '123'

My Alternative PHP:

`$taxpath = $_FILES["TaxFile"]["tmp_name"];
$ext = pathinfo($taxpath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $ext;`

echos nothing

I expected to see the echo:
"pdf
123"
and "pdf"

*My later code does in fact save the file to its destination using `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["TaxFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)`. It's just that $target_file wont include the proper extension.

Comment: The temporary file on the server does not any extension. It's mostly a random string generated by PHP.

Comment: Thank you Álvaro González, that explains why it kept returning as null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp_name` is the temporary name/location of the file on disk.

Try using `$_FILES["TaxFile"]["name"]` to get the original filename.

Otherwise, your method for grabbing the extension with `pathinfo()` and  `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` was correct.

Comment: Thank you,
This resolved the issue. Thank you for explaining the difference between "tmp_name" and "name".

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you if you use `name` instead of `tmp_name`

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["TaxFile"]['name']);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
echo $extension;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems I didn't know the difference between "tmp_name" and "name".

Answer (score 1):

This will solve

```
$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

so in your file concatenate the variables

```
echo $path.'.'.$ext;
```